# Gmail API を利用した自作のwebメーラーで、GSuite 以外のアカウントからのアクセス時にエラー "403: org_internal"

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

私の提供するWebサイト（Webメーラー）からGMailをOAuth2.0認証で利用するために、GMailAPIを作成しました。
GSuiteアカウントで作成して、同組織からは使えるのですが、フリーアカウント等から利用できません。

```
エラー 403: org_internal
This client is restricted to users within its organization.
```

このAPIを一般公開して、だれでも利用が可能なようにするには、どのような設定を行えば良いでしょうか？

類似としては、ExcangeOnlineの場合、Azure API Managementを契約してAPIを公開するようです。
GoogleのAPIも同様に専用のプランなどがありますでしょうか？

**追記**
APIはGoogleが提供するGmail APIを利用します。
上記APIを利用するため、GoogleCloudPlatformにてプロジェクトを作成して、Gmail APIを有効化
利用するための認証情報として、OAuthクライアントIDを作成し、OAuth同意画面を作成
Webメーラーから上記で作成したOAuthクライアントIDのIDとクライアントシークレットを、
OAuth同意画面へ引き渡して、認証情報の同意を求めるのですが、G Suite以外のアカウントから、その同意画面にて前述のエラーが発生します。
私の提供するWebメーラーの利用者の方に、上記のOAuth同意画面を使って頂くための公開方法を探しております。

Comment: 誰でも＝スパム業者でも、ということでエラーメッセージの通り「同一組織内でのみ使える」よう制約されている現状が適切であって、一般公開するのは悪用されるリスクが大だと思います。その辺どう対処するのでしょうか？

Comment: クライアントIDやクライアントシークレット等のAPIを利用する上で必要となる情報は公開しない予定なので、APIを公開しても私の意図したアプリからしか使えない予定です。

Comment: 「私の意図したアプリからしか使えない予定」でセキュリティは保証できるのですか？

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent で内部になっている、あるいはUser Typeが選択されていない、などですか？(すでにセキュリティ云々の話がされていますが、関連してgmailまわりのスコープは[restricted scope](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)なようです)

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - [Can't login using Google Auth, 403: org_internal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54629180)

Comment: @hinaloe
こちらのコメント、ありがとうございます。
ご案内頂いた設定箇所にて解決できました。